# How to get a approx nature of $f'''(x)$ graph from the given data ( Graph techinque using LMVT etc., or using just calculus both suffices )

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The above mentioned title is for giving a rough graph for $f'''(x)$ , such that we can show that there exists some values of $f'''(c) \ge 6$. Problem where i encountered this:  " If $f(x)$ is a function with a continuous third derivative on $[0, 2]$ such that
$f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = f'(2) = f''(2) = 0$ and $f(2) = 2$, then minimum number of value(s) of $c$ belongs $[0, 2]$
such that $f'''(c)\ge 6$ ", What I tried is that I draw graphs of $f(x) ,f'(x) , f''(x)$ and tried to use LMVT to conclude something useful for $f'''(x)$ ,but seems like graph way is too much messy and I know there are many cases which the graph can be for every type , so I thought some calculus way might be there leaving the graph technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third derivative is very hard to see from a graph.  It can make a sharp corner on a graph.  Your function starts out very flat at $0$ and ends up very flat at $2$.  If the third derivative is small the function can't rise very quickly from $0$ and won't have time to get to $2$.  You are told the Taylor series at $0$ is $kx^3$ plus higher order terms and the Taylor series at $2$ is $2+k'(x-2)^3$ plus higher order terms.

If there are no points where the third derivative is $6$ or greater, you can bound the second derivative by integrating $6$.  You can integrate twice more and bound the value of the function from above.  You can do the same starting from $2$ and going downwards.  If you can make the values and derivatives match you can exhibit a function that never touches $6$ and claim victory.

If not, you probably need $f'''(x) \ge 6$ over an interval, so the number of points is uncountable.  A more interesting question would be to show you can succeed with just one interval.  Intuitively you could jump with a(n almost) square wave from $0$ to almost $2$ with one bit of $f'''(x) \ge 6$.  Can you slow down enough to arrive at the other end without the third derivative getting large?

Comment: Sir very very thx for your thought process :) , some points i didnt get quite gud , how is third derivative of the function very small in [0,2] tells that function cant rise very quickly, i dont have a gud visulization for thrid derivate thats why the above point is a bit not understandable for me . Also i didnt quite get what u meant by" starting from 2 and get the function "as such i from your first point f'''(x)<= 6 i integrated it thrice to get a condition for f(x) , now what to do and about the higher terms in taylor expansion ?

Comment: If the third derivative is less than $6$, near $0$ it must be (roughly) less than $x^3$ because the third derivative of that is $6$.  Similarly around $2$ it must be (roughly) greater than $(2-x)^3$ because the third derivative of that around $2$ is $6$

Comment: Sir i integrated f'''(x) < 6 over the region [0,2] to get f(x)<x^3 +ax^2/2+ a_1 x+ a_2 , from ur first thing to integrate it three times , now by comparing it with either taylor at x=0 or x= 2 we can deduce k ,k'<1 ,now what to do ? And why greater sir , we want less isnt in (x-2)^3 too isnt the third derivative?

Comment: And Sir answer is actually 1, there exists atleast 1 value of c such that third derivative is greater than or equal to 6

Comment: If you have a term like $ax^2/2$ it will exceed $x^3$ for small enough $x$, so you know $a=0$.  Similarly for $a_1, a_2$.  That is an important point of this exercise.  Over small distances the lower derivatives will dominate, so if you have a bound on the third derivative (given that the others start at $0$) the others must be zero.

Comment: Sir is there a proof somewhere in the site where its shown that for a bound on a nth derivative the lower ones must have their coefficient zero in polynomial form , this is kinda new  thing to me :) and Sir after your fact now i guess there is no such function. Just can u explain a bit about "how we can succeeed with just one interval ? Can u slow down enough to arrive at other end "

Comment: You should have a theorem that $\int_0^t f(x)dx \lt |\max (f(x))|t$.  Apply this two levels down, then integrate two more times.  That is the point of the exercise.  If we ignore the limitation near $x=0$ we still have the problem of arriving at $x=2$ with the required derivatives.  I suspect that the problem means we can violate the restriction on the third derivative over an interval near $x=0$, not just at one point.  We can then have a sharp corner, but are asking if we can find a function that doesn't have another one.

Comment: Yup Sir they asked for a point in [0,2] which can make all conditions given work. Can we find the c exactly so that we can get a function having just one point where third derivative is greater than 6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120277/discussion-between-wizardmath-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: One point where the derivative is high doesn't matter to the function above.  You need the derivative high over an interval.  You should have a theorem that says changing one point of the function does not change the integral.

Comment: An example of a function that almost works is $f(x)=x^3$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x)=2-(2-x)^3$ for $1 \lt x \le 2$.  That has third derivative $6$ on the first half and $-6$ on the second half.  The function and first and third derivatives are continuous but the second jumps from $6$ to $-6$ at $1$ so the third is not defined at $1$.

Comment: Sorry, the third derivative is $6$ everywhere it is defined, which is everywhere except $1$

Comment: Aa yes Sir, that function i understood , but we want to find minimum values of c such that f'''(c)>=6 , as answer is 1 , so i expected the function to be like this : we have a function where f'''(x) <6 upto z , where z is in [0,z) and after that (z,2] function has a f"'(x) <6  only at z f"'(z)=6,   but i dont have a proof if there is such function

Comment: Is my thinking correct Sir?

Comment: As I commented earlier, changing the derivative at one point does not change the function.  The minimum number of points where the third derivative is greater than $6$ can only be zero or $\mathfrak c$.  The question here is which.  In my next to last comment I gave an example which avoided having the third derivative greater than $6$ where it was defined, but it failed to be continuous because it was not defined at $1$.  When you asked the question originally it asked about points where the third derivative was greater than or equal to $6$.  For my example, that was all of $[0,2]$ less one.

Comment: You should be able to use my example to bound any other function with third derivative strictly less than $6$ and show it cannot meet the requirement.  That shows there must be continuum many points where the derivative is $6$ or greater.

Comment: Got your pt Sir ty